# Loading an image into imageView using Flickr API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to load a single image into an `imageView` using a URL retrieved using Flickr's API

A get an array of photo objects using:

```
private func performSearchWithText(searchText: String) {
  UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
  FlickrProvider.fetchPhotosForSearchText(searchText: searchText, onCompletion: { (error: NSError?, flickrPhotos: [FlickrPhoto]?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
      self.photos = flickrPhotos!
    } else {
      self.photos = []
      if (error!.code == FlickrProvider.Errors.invalidAccessErrorCode) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
          self.showErrorAlert()
        })
      }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
      self.loadImageWithUrl()
    })
  })
}
```

That last method call `self.loadImageWithUrl()` should load *one* of the images into an `imageView` via a `pop()`:

```
private func loadImageWithUrl() {
  var photo = photos.popLast()
  if photo != nil {
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: photo!.photoUrl.absoluteURL as URL!)
  }
}
```

The photo never loads, and I get the following error in debugger:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I am new to to Swift, so please forgive any obvious pitfalls or an error in semantics.

Comment: What is the entire error you are getting?

Comment: The imageView never loads an image, and that thread 1 error shows up in debugger. I think it is a threading issue with how I’m using async. That is the entirety of the error to my knowledge. @StephenPaul

Comment: What is `sd_setImage`?

Comment: @matt `sd_setImage` sets an imageView using a provided URL

Comment: Yes, but can you show it? This is not a native UIImageView method.

Comment: @matt that is a method from `SDWebImage` library.

Comment: @JacobRussell Any updates on your progress? Just want to make sure you have found a solution to your problem.

Comment: @StephenPaul I️ updated below, thanks so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which line does the debugger stop in the code? What could be causing your issue is a variable that is `nil` and it's being force-unwrapped in your code. So let's clean this code up a bit.

It isn't "safe" for you to assume that you will always be returned a value from an optional, so you need to guard against the possible case of `nil` or your app will be error prone. It also looks like you want to load the `imageView` with an image, but that should only happen if 1) there are no errors and 2) you have a data source from which to load your `imageView`, so why not do that inside the closure?

```
private func performSearchWithText(searchText: String) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    FlickrProvider.fetchPhotosForSearchText(searchText: searchText, onCompletion: { (error: NSError?, flickrPhotos: [FlickrPhoto]?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showErrorAlert()
            }
        } else {
            guard let photos = flickrPhotos else {
                self.photos = []
                return
            }
            self.photos = photos
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.loadImageWithUrl()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even that can be cleaned up further if you make your `photos` variable optional. Anyways, try that code and see if you still get that crash.

Comment: Thanks! I️ was able to stop the crash with this fix, and found a secondary issue with my API call. This also helped clarify the update Swift 3 made to dispatchQueue, which I️ was confused on.

Comment: Great! I'm happy that helped.